# A Question With Logs

Tags: probability, logarithms

If we define $\ln^+(n)=max(1,\ln(n))$ and $\ln^{(k)}(n)$ to be the multi-fold log function (such as $\ln^{(2)}(n)=\ln^+\ln^+(n)$ and we know the following:

$$
Prob(f(n)<g(n)\ln^{(k)}(n))=1
$$

for any positive integer $k$ and $n$ a random positive integer, can we take the limit as $k$ goes to infinity and get the following?

$$
Prob(f(n)\leq g(n))=1
$$

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(f(n)<g(n)\log^{(k)}(n))=1$ works for which $k$ ? Because $k=0$ would give you the result.

Comment: @Tuvasbien The question says any positive $k$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien the natural definition of $\log^{(0)}(n)$ would be $n$, not $1$

Comment: Can you say that for any $n$ there is a $k$ such that $\ln^{(k)}(n) =1$ ?  Would that be enough for your conclusion, or does it matter that such a $k$ may vary with $n$?

Comment: Apparently $n$ is a random variable here? What is its domain and distribution?

Comment: @GregMartin $n$ is a randomly chosen integer. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Henry That might be enough, but I don't think one can find a $k$ for every $n$ since $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Take $f(n) =g(n)$ and $n > e$.  Then $\ln^+ n > 1$ by induction then $\ln^k n > 1$ so $Prod(f(n) < g(n)\ln^k(n) ) = 1$ but $Prob(f(n) < g(n)) = 0$.... It's always possible for $\lim a_n = L$ even if every $a_n < L$.  In fact that is *very* common.  However if $f(n) < g(n) \ln^k n $ for all $k$ then $f(n) \le g(n)$ can be concluded.

Comment: If each positive integer $n$ is chosen with probability $p_n$ where $\sum_{n\ge1} p_n=1$, then saying an event happens with probability $1$ is the same as saying that the inequality defining the event definitely holds for all $n$ for which $p_n>0$. Then @Henry's suggestion can be carried out one such $n$ at a time.

Comment: @Samuel $k=\lceil n \rceil$ is more than big enough or $k=n$ if both are integers

Comment: " can we take the limit as k goes to infinity and get the following"  No.   $a_k < 1$ does *not* mean that $\lim a_k < 1$.  You could have $\lim a_k = 1$.

Comment: So it seems I could change it to $Prob(f(n)\leq g(n)$) to get around the limit issue? @GregMartin that is indeed true, but in my case all integers have equal probability making none of them positive.

Comment: @Henry I believe you are correct. I can choose any positive integer $k$ for each positive integer $n$ such that $\ln^{(k)}(n)=1$ and $k=n$ is way more than necessary.

Comment: @Samuel It's not possible to have a probability measure on the set of positive integers that selects each integer with equal probability.